# Url opens only on clicking link

Tags: url

Is there a way to ensure that a url successfully loads page only on clicking the link provided on a page and preventing url to open if the url is copy pasted in the browser address bar and Enter key is pressed ? 
Edit
Session variables is the answer .. very silly question

Comment: No, unless you develop your own browser.

Comment: How is C# related to this?

Comment: It is a general question not related to c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can't be outright prevented from this.

You can try to make it tough though, for example through hidden POST data or through a "proxy" link which acts as a gateway to your page. Session variables come to mind in this case, since you have effectively moved the locking logic server-side.

Answer (score 4):

**You can't**. Its a browser function  and you don't have any control over it.